# Pandas: Change datatype in columns and then multiply two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported two files as DataFrames and want to multiply 'New Price' but '12 Month Quantity Ordered'. I though that I had successfully changed the columns from strings to a number in order to be able to multiply these two columns. And it seems that I did something wrong.

I want to change the data types so I can multiply the two columns and then add that columns to the end of the DataFrame.

Then I would like to get sum the multiplied prices.

Here is my code that failed.

`Comparisonfile[['New Price']].convert_objects(convert_numeric =True)
      Comparisonfile[['12 Month Quantity Ordered']].convert_objects(convert_numeric =True)`

```
  Comparisonfile[['12 Month Quantity Ordered']].convert_objects(convert_numeric =True)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-e8d0f16b4286> in <module>()
----> 1 Comparisonfile['Proposed Ext. Price'] = Comparisonfile['New
     Price']*Comparisonfile['12 Month Quantity Ordered']

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in wrapper(self, other, name)
162             if self.index.equals(other.index):
163                 name = _maybe_match_name(self, other)
--> 164                 return Series(wrap_results(na_op(lvalues, rvalues)),
165                               index=self.index, name=name, dtype=dtype)
166 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in na_op(x, y)
 72             if isinstance(y, pa.Array):
 73                 mask = notnull(x) & notnull(y)
---> 74                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], y[mask])
 75             else:
 76                 mask = notnull(x)

 TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I thought I had changed the values of the columns...

Comment: you need to assign the converted objects to something (its not inplace)

Answer (score 1):

The convert function does not keep the converted data but returns it.  You must save it back over the old data if you want it.

```
Comparisonfile['New Price'] = Comparisonfile['New Price'].convert_objects(convert_numeric =True) 
Comparisonfile['12 Month Quantity Ordered'] = Comparisonfile['12 Month Quantity Ordered'].convert_objects(convert_numeric =True)
```

Many function in pandas behave this way.  Some have an `inplace` option, although `convert_objects` does not appear to be one of them.